# Use Value of a Nested Callback as Return for Parent Function

Tags: javascript, image

So, I have this:

```
function isOnline(sURL) {

    var bOnline,
        oImage = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("img") );

    oImage.onload = function() {

        bOnline = true;

    };

    oImage.onerror = function() {

        bOnline = false;

    };

    oImage.src = sURL;

    return bOnline;

}
```

... and I've had this problem before yet gotten around but I'm a little lost here.  How can I get the value of `bOnline` to pass to `isOnline` at the right time?  As expected, it returns `undefined` (initially).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't delay the return statement like this. What you can do is pass an additional callback into this function and call that callback once you know the result.

Comment: Good show.  Let me mock this up.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use callback functions in such situations as given below

```
var online = false;

isOnline("htp://....", function(){
   online = true;
}, function(){
   online = false;
});

function isOnline(sURL, onLoad, onError) {

    var oImage = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("img") );

    oImage.onload = onLoad;

    oImage.onerror = onError;

    oImage.src = sURL;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you use a callback to continue your logic :

```
 function isOnline(sURL, callbacks){
     var bOnline,
         oImage = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("img") );
     oImage.onerror = callbacks.error;
     oImage.onload = callbacks.success;
     oImage.src = sURL;
 }
```

And instead of a call like this :

```
if(isOnline('some-src')) {
    // good stuff
} else {
   // bad stuff
}
```

you should use the function like :

```
isOnline('some-src',{
    success : function(){
        // yey! image is online
    },
    error : function(){
       // eerror loading image. boo :((
    }
});
```

If you still want to test at some point in time without using callbacks, you can return the actual image object and pin a `ready` or `error` flag on it :

```
function isOnline(sURL) {
    var bOnline,
        oImage = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("img") );
    oImage.ready = oImage.error = false;
    oImage.onload = function(){
        oImage.ready = true;
    }
    oImage.error= function(){
        oImage.error = true;
    }
    oImage.src = sURL;
    return oImage;
}


var img = isOnline('some-src');
// .. after some computing
if(img.ready) {
    // yey image  has loaded
} else if(img.error) {
   // damn error :(
} else {
   // still not loaded :-?
}
```